# Fill dictonary values as the sum of values from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary that contains the names of various players with all values set to `None` like so...

```py
players = {'A': None,
           'B': None,
           'C': None,
           'D': None,
           'E': None}
```

A pandas data frame (df_1) that contains the keys, i.e. player names

```
   col_0  col_1  col_2
   -----  -----  -----
0    A       B      C
1    A       E      D
2    C       B      A
```

and a dataframe (df_2) that contains their scores in corresponding matches

```
    score_0  score_1  score_2
     -----    -----    -----
0      1       10        2
1      6       15        7
2      8       1         9
```

Hence, total score of A is..

```
      1       +      6        +      9         =  16
(0, score_0)  + (1, score_0)  + (2, score_2)
```

and I would like to map all the players(A, B, C..) to their total score in the dictionary of players that I had created earlier.

Here's some code that I wrote...

```py
for player in players:
  players[player] = df_2.loc[df_1['col_0'] == player, 'score_0'].sum()
  players[player] += df_2.loc[df_1['col_1'] == player, 'score_1'].sum()
  players[player] += df_2.loc[df_1['col_2'] == player, 'score_2'].sum()
print(players)
```

This produces the desired result, but I am wondering if a faster, more pandas like way is available. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ummm `pandas` `stack` , usually we can `groupby` after flatten the df

```
s=df2.stack().groupby(df1.stack().values).sum()
s
A    16
B    11
C    10
D     7
E    15
dtype: int64
s.to_dict()
{'A': 16, 'B': 11, 'C': 10, 'D': 7, 'E': 15}
```

Comment: and a `.to_dict()` awesome, i was trying with`replace` and `get` and what not :/

Comment: This is a great answer, however, do note that length of `df2.stack()` and `df1.stack()` must be same. If they are not (due to missing values), then you should consider filling all missing  values with `df.fillna()`. If that is not feasible, @Willem_Van_Onsem's answer with it's optimisation is also a great option.

Answer (score 4):

You can generate such dictionary with:

```
import numpy as np
result = { k: np.nansum(df_2[df_1 == k]) for k in players }
```

For the given sample data, this will return:

```
>>> { k: np.nansum(df_2[df_1 == k]) for k in players }
{'A': 16.0, 'B': 11.0, 'C': 10.0, 'D': 7.0, 'E': 15.0}
```

Given no values for the given key exist, it will map to zero. For example if we add a key `R` to the `players`:

```
>>> players['R'] = None
>>> { k: np.nansum(df_2[df_1 == k]) for k in players }
{'A': 16.0, 'B': 11.0, 'C': 10.0, 'D': 7.0, 'E': 15.0, 'R': 0.0}
```

Or we can boost efficiency by first extracting numpy arrays out of the data frames:

```
arr_2 = df_2.values
arr_1 = df_1.values   

result = { k: arr_2[arr_1 == k].sum() for k in players }
```

## Benchmarks

If we define functions `f` (the original implemention) `g` (this implementation), and `h` (@WeNYoBen's implementation), and we use `timeit` to measure the time for 1'000 calls with the given sample data, I get the following for an Intel Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz (that is unfortunately a bit buzy at the moment):

```
>>> df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_0': ['A', 'A', 'C'], 'col_1': ['B', 'E', 'B'], 'col_2': ['C', 'D', 'A']})
>>> df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'score_0': [1, 6, 8], 'score_1': [10, 15, 1], 'score_2': [2, 7, 9]})
>>> def f():
...     for player in players:
...       players[player] = df_2.loc[df_1['col_0'] == player, 'score_0'].sum()
...       players[player] += df_2.loc[df_1['col_1'] == player, 'score_1'].sum()
...       players[player] += df_2.loc[df_1['col_2'] == player, 'score_2'].sum()
...     return players
...
>>> def g():
...     arr_2 = df_2.values
...     arr_1 = df_1.values    
...     result = { k: arr_2[arr_1 == k].sum() for k in players }
...
>>> def h():
...     return df_2.stack().groupby(df_1.stack().values).sum().to_dict()
... 
>>> timeit(f, number=1000)
47.23081823496614
>>> timeit(g, number=1000)
0.32561282289680094
>>> timeit(h, number=1000)
8.169926556991413
```

The most important optimization is probably to use the numpy array instead of performing the calculations at the pandas level.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I tried your method and timed it against mine, it seems to take more time than the one that I have used before asking this question.

Comment: @SudeepamPandey: for performance, it is better to first extract numpy arrays out of dataframes.

Comment: @SudeepamPandey: after the last optimization, I get a speedup of approximately 145 times compared to the implementation in the question.